# Change icon depending on boolean variable

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to switch from one icon to another depending on a boolean variable.

For example, I have the following icon:

```
<v-icon class="mr-3"> mdi-play </v-icon>
```

I have a boolean variable 'playing' which is initialised to false.
When 'playing' is False I want the icon to be 'mdi-play', but when the 'playing' variable changes to True I wish for the icon to switch to 'mdi-pause'. What would be the best way of achieving this? I have attempted binding v-text like so, but with no success:

```
<v-icon :v-text="playing ? 'mdi-pause' : 'mdi-play'" class="mr-3"></v-icon>
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directive should not be bound using `:`, in your example you could simple do :

```
<v-icon  class="mr-3">{{playing ? 'mdi-pause' : 'mdi-play'}}</v-icon>
```